# Why is this Javascript Initial Cap Function Not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component with a select box which allows the user to select one of four "severity" labels, and by virtue of the API the variable must be lowercase. This is the select box ...

```
  <select id="logs-select" onChange={this.handleSeverityChange} value={this.state.dropSeverity}>
                          <option value="">Select: </option>
                          <option value="info">Info</option>
                          <option value="warning">Warning</option>
                          <option value="error">Error</option>
                          <option value="fatal">Fatal</option>
                        </select>
```

There are three other select boxes on the page and thanks to the wonderful folks on this site I have the following function which wonderfully outputs the variables to a URL ...

```
   const names = [
  "severity",
  "domain",
  "device",
  "start",
  "end"
]

    const selectProps = {
  selectedseverity: this.state.dropSeverity,
  selecteddomain: this.state.dropDomain,
  selecteddevice: this.state.dropDevice,
  selectedstart: this.state.startDate,
  selectedend: this.state.endDate
}

let url = `/inventory_reporter_api/logs?stage=PRODUCTION&` + names
.filter(name => selectProps["selected" + name] !== '')
.map(name => name.toLowerCase() + "=" + encodeURIComponent(selectProps["selected" + name]))
.join("&");
```

However, I am also outputting a headline which needs the "severity" variable to be initial cap. Here is my current function:

```
let headline = `Logs for ` + names
.filter(name => selectProps["selected" + name] !== '')
.map(name => decodeURI(selectProps["selected" + name]) + " " + name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1))
.join(" - ");
console.log('this is the headline ', headline)
```

The "name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.substr(1)" script is working beautifully to make the "Severity" to initial cap in the headline but I cannot figure out how to transform the selected severity variable to initial cap. I am guessing that I going to need to add some javascript on the ".map" line in my headline creation function but am not quite sure how to do it. I hope my explanation and code are adequate. I got a warning about a couple of my previous questions and consider this site and all of the help I have received so valuable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.map(name =>  {
  const newName = name.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + name.slice(1);
  return decodeURI(selectProps["selected" + name]) + " " + newName;
}),
```

you almost had it, if i understood you correctly something like this should work.

Comment: oh man this looks a game ON. I will try it ASAP. Thank you so much for your time and help.

Comment: Still getting lower case in the headline, unfortunately.

Comment: Actually I am wrong it's now returning "undefined" for the severity variable.

Comment: that's because i made i mistake in the return statement, i've edited it, please re-check.

Comment: I'm now getting the variable returned but it's lower case.

Comment: your own code should've worked fine to begin with, i had definitely misunderstood your question, I quickly tested it locally assuming states as 'test' and this is what i got.

http://prntscr.com/m72d2i

on the other hand, it would be much better to use css to capitalize the output, all you have to do is, add `text-transform: capitalize`

good luck.